# Does React run in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Once i created a build from my project i decided to take a look at the JS file produced in the build process and i found uglified code that i couldn't understand but at the first glimpse it seems that there is much code added by **React** that will work in the browser!

Now i am confused about what is the part of **React** that works in the browser, is the whole library added to the build file or certain functions from **React** + my code??

I understand that JSX part need to be compiled to work in the browser but what about other react functions, how they looks like after build?? how are they used by the browser??

Comment: It all goes to JavaScript, HTML, and CSS, and runs in the browser from there.